# Input field with required fields

Tags: javascript, validation, codeigniter-3

html

```
<form action="" id="formsave">
  <div class="row">
    <input type="text" id="test1"name="test1">
    <input type="text" id="test2"name="test2">
  </div>
</form>
```

I have two input fields, If test1 have a value it required test2 if not it would not required. It means if test1 is have a value, you cannot save the form without test2 value. if test1 is null test2 is not required.

Comment: Looks you could need the `Knockout` Javascript framework. Also, what is your question?

Comment: My question is how to required test2 fields if test1 fields have a value.

Comment: You tagged your question with javascript, but do not show your JS code. I would definitely go through a javascript tutorial, and a jquery tutorial. Knockout is nice, but looking at your question, not for now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        function check() {
            var test1 = document.getElementById("test1").value
            var test2 = document.getElementById("test2").value



            if ((!!test1 && !!test2) || !test1) {
                return true
            } else {
                document.getElementById("errmsg").innerHTML = "test2 required"
                return false
            }


        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form onsubmit="return check()">
        <input type="text" id="test1">
        <input type="text" id="test2">
        <input type="submit">
        <div id="errmsg"></div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: dgoku, Im using form submit. if this applicable with that?

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of test1 when the form is saved.

```
$("#save").on('click', function() {
    if($("#test1").val()) {
        alert("please enter all data");
    } else {
        $("#formsave").submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: If test1 have a value it required test2 fields to have a value. If test1 is null, test is not required.

Comment: @PaulMBactin That is what it does. It checks if test1 has value. If it has then alert is shown to enter all data. Else form is saved

Answer (score 0):

Something like that

```
var form = document.getElementById('formsave'),
    check = function() {
        var input1 = document.getElementById('test1'),
            input2 = document.getElementById('test2');

        if (input1.value !== '' && input2.value === '') {
            return false;
        } else return true;
    };

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    if (check()) {
        // do stuff here
    } else e.preventDefault();
});
```